# Using RefactorThis.GraphDiff library

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the following tables in my database

[image]

And a graph mapping of *(table address not shown in image)*:

```
.OwnedEntity(s => s.Address)
.OwnedCollection(s => s.SiteActivityPlants)
.OwnedCollection(s => s.SiteActivityPlants, with => with.AssociatedCollection(d => d.SiteActivityPlantNotes))
```

What I am trying to do is update the data in table SiteActivityPlantNotes.

After looking at [Documentation](http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/updates-to-graphdiff-with-new-scenarios-supported/), AssociatedCollection just updates the reference, what I need to do is update the data records within SiteActivityPlantNotes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Changes in your code should do it:

- Removed second line ".OwnedCollection(s => s.SiteActivityPlants)"
  as it is already part of the third line
- Changed in third line "with.AssociatedCollection" to
  "with.OwnedCollection"

Final Code:

```
.OwnedEntity(s => s.Address)
.OwnedCollection(s => s.SiteActivityPlants, with => with.OwnedCollection(d => d.SiteActivityPlantNotes))
```